# scala-parser-combinators: opt() and "|" combination, strange results

Tags: scala, parsing

I am trying to implement an ISO 8601 date/time format parser and experiencing some troubles with optional parts of time. I have constructed a simplified example of my problem:

```
class ISO8601 extends RegexParsers {
  val hour = s"[0-9]{2}".r ^^ {_.toInt}
  val minute = s"[0-9]{2}".r ^^ {_.toInt}
  val timeSep = ":"
  val test = (hour ~ opt(timeSep ~> minute) |
    hour ~ opt(minute)) ^^ {
    case hh ~ mmOpt =>
      val mm = mmOpt.getOrElse(0)
      (hh, mm, 0, 0)
  }
}
```

What I wanted to do is to allow the following time formats:

- hh
- hhmm
- hh:mm

My parser successfully parses "23" and "23:30" but rejects to parse "2330":

```
isoRes: iso.ParseResult[(Int, Int, Int, Int)] = [1.3] failure: string matching regex `\z' expected but `3' found

2330
```

Should not parser backtrack on that failure and try to match the second option (after "|")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `opt()` parser. First, I'm assuming you're calling it like this:

```
parseAll(ISO8601.test, new CharSequenceReader("2330"))
```

So what happens? `parseAll` will try to parse the all input in the reader, i.e until it returns no more characters.

So the `test` parser is used, it tries the first alternative and parses "23". Then there is no separator, so the `opt()` parser will return `None` and the first alternative succeeds. So there is no need to check the second alternative. Then there is still the characters `3` and `0` in the reader, but the parser expected to be at the end of the input! That's why you get a failure.

Now try with:

```
println(ISO8601.parseAll(ISO8601.rep(ISO8601.test), new CharSequenceReader("2330")))
```

it outputs:

```
[1.5] parsed: List((23,0,0,0), (30,0,0,0))
```

so you see that the first alternative has been used 2 times.

So how can you fix it? One alternative would be to make the minutes optional and the separator in the minutes optional too.

```
def test = hour ~ opt(opt(timeSep) ~> minute) map {
    case h ~ None => (h, 0, 0, 0)
    case h ~ Some(mm) => (h, mm, 0, 0)
}
```

Running it successively with "23", "2330", "23:30", you get:

```
[1.3] parsed: (23,0,0,0)
[1.6] parsed: (23,30,0,0)
[1.5] parsed: (23,30,0,0)
```

By the way, you should add some checks in the `hour` and `minute` parsers otherwise `"9999"` is a valid input.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
val time = "^([0-9]{2}):?([0-9]{0,2})$".r
def parse(str: String) = str match {
  case time(h, m) => (h, if (m == "") 0 else m, 0, 0)
}

parse("12")
parse("13:21")
parse("1456")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I have figured it out myself.

The reason is that the first alternative **matches** consuming only "23",
so the **test** term is "23" and the rest of imput is "30". 
Then the parser expects the end of input but sees remaining "30".

```
class ISO8601 extends RegexParsers {
  val hour = s"[0-9]{2}".r ^^ {_.toInt}
  val minute = s"[0-9]{2}".r ^^ {_.toInt}
  val timeSep = ":"
  val test = (hour ~ (timeSep ~> minute) |
    hour ~ success(0) |
    hour ~ minute) ^^ { case hh ~ mm => (hh, mm, 0, 0) }
}
```

However, if I add seconds and milliseconds, the term seems quite inelegant:

```
val time = (hour ~ (timeSep ~> minute) ~ (timeSep ~> second) ~ (msSep ~> ms) |
  hour ~ (timeSep ~> minute) ~ (timeSep ~> second) ~ success(0) |
  hour ~ (timeSep ~> minute) ~ success(0) ~ success(0) |
  hour ~ success(0) ~ success(0) ~ success(0) |
  hour ~ minute ~ second ~ (msSep ~> ms) |
  hour ~ minute ~ second ~ (msSep ~> success(0)) |
  hour ~ minute ~ second ~ success(0) |
  hour ~ minute ~ success(0) ~ success(0)
  ) ^^ {
  case hh ~ mm ~ ss ~ sss =>
    (hh, mm, ss, sss)
}
```

And I do not see a way to fix it.